# Missing image in Jasper Reports

Tags: java, swing, io, jasper-reports, report

I am trying to generate a Jasper report from my Java code, my Java application is Swing. I designed the Jasper report using the `TIBCO Jaspersoft Studio 6.0.0 final`. However, in my report, there is a Logo image. The image location is dynamically passed, it works fine when previewed on Jaspersoft Studio. Below is how the image is set in JasperSoft studio.The `imagePath` variable is `String`

```
<image>
    <reportElement x="210" y="0" width="140" height="76" uuid="2c20bfe9-e8af-4ca4-9c06-3c81ebe5f8a1"/>
    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{imagePath}]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

This is how I generate the report in Java.

```
private class PrintClientListBtnAction implements ActionListener
     {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            ReportConnector r = new ReportHandler();
            try {
                HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                params.put("imagePath", ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("/ReportResources/Logo_Big2i.png"));
                r.printReport(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/ReportResources/Core_Clients.jasper"), params);

            } catch (JRException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getLocalizedMessage(),"Printing error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }

     }
```

The problem is, the report generated by the Java code do not have an image! what is wrong here?

**Update**

I tried with `imagePath` as `InputStream` as well, but the same result is here...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your images should be loaded through the system class loader. Try replacing

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(
```

By

```
PrintClientListBtnAction.class.getResourceAsStream(
```